# Why Am I Getting An Error When Connecting To Google Search Console API Via Flask Dance?

Tags: oauth, google-search-console, flask-dance

Im creating a flask app that retrieves data from Google Search Console API.

However I'm having hard times implementing Google OAuth with Flask-Dance.

I am getting the following error:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_dance.contrib.google import make_google_blueprint, google
import os


def create_app(config_name):
    os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
    os.environ['OAUTHLIB_RELAX_TOKEN_SCOPE'] = '1'   
    print(config_name)
    blueprint = make_google_blueprint(
    client_id={MY CLIENT ID},
    client_secret={MY SECRET},
    scope=["profile", "email"])
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    google_bp = make_google_blueprint(scope=["profile","email","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters"])

    @app.route("/search")
    def search():
        if not google.authorized:
            return redirect(url_for("google.login"))
        request = {
'startDate': '2019-01-01',
'endDate': '2019-01-31','dimensions': ['query']}
        resp = google.post("/webmasters/v3/sites/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com/searchAnalytics/query", json=request)
        amt=resp['rows'][0]['clicks']
        return '<h1>'+amt+'</h1>'


    return app
```

I have also set up the application in Google Developers Console following the below steps, outlined here:
https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/v0.8.0/quickstarts/google.html

[image]

Any ideas what might be the issue?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, `client_id=None`, it looks like you have some misconfiguration. In your code, there are two `make_google_blueprint`.

You can review your code again to fix this problem.